# GeoProjection used in area computation of relatively small regions

Tags: geometry, geographics

Let's define a relatively small region via GeoPosition as follows.

```
pos = GeoPosition[{{48, 9}, {48.0001, 9}, {48.0001, 9.0001}, {48, 9.0001}}, "WGS84"]
```

The area of the corresponding polygon

```
Area[Polygon[pos]]
```

is computed as

```
Quantity[82.97546880692244`, Power["Meters", 2]]
```

How can one obtain this result from the corresponding `GeoGridPosition`? One relatively close result is computed by

```
Area@Polygon@GeoGridPosition[pos, {"Albers", "ReferenceModel" -> "WGS84"}]["GridXY"]
```

namely

```
82.9761
```

A slightly better one is obtained using the projection `"SPCS27MT01"`. However, some other projections yield significantly different results for this relatively small region.

What is the "right" choice when computing the area of relatively small regions from the corresponding `GeoGridPosition`?